# C++ namespace issues with third party library and same name classes

Tags: c++, class, namespaces, sfml

I defined a Vector2 class in my project

```
class Vector2
{
public:
    Vector2();
    ~Vector2();
protected:
    float mX;
    float mY;
}
```

I started using a library called [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/)

Amongst other things, it handles drawing shapes and images for me.

SFML [defines it's own Vector2](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1Vector2.php) class. Obviously, this lead to some namespace issues. Here's how I resolve it:

```
// Using an SFML Vector2
sf::Vector2 sfmlVector;

// Using my Vector2
::Vector2 myVector;
```

I would prefer that "Vector2" is always assumed to be my vector2, and "sf::Vector2" is always SFML's vector2, rather than having to put in a namespace to my vector2 or using the messier global :: namespace.

Can this be done?

Comment: Don't `using namespace sf` if you want that behavior.

Comment: I would put your classes in a namespace too.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you are not adding code inside the `sf` namespace, lookup will not try to find `Vector2` inside that namespace, and will find the global namespace one. If you are adding code inside the `sf` namespace then it will find `sf::Vector2` first... but I would consider that code *in* the library should use the type *in* the library.

Comment: Hmm, I definitley do not have the code within the sf namespace. Perhaps I do in some file, and down the include tree, it looks at the "using sf" file first and flips out then? I'll try removing all "using sf" and manually calling sf:: on the files that do that, and see if it helps.

Comment: You should avoid using directives for exactly this reason: namespace are tools to separate identifiers and avoid collision, using directives have the opposite effect in that they *merge* namespaces and cause collisions

Answer (score 1):

I would still put your own `Vector2` class into your own namespace, to avoid polluting the global one.  When using the class, though, if specifying the namespace every time gets tiresome, you could use the [using declaration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/was37tzw%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), like so:

```
using mynamespace::Vector2;
```

to tell the compiler to resolve `Vector2` to your vector type for the rest of the file (translation unit).

Comment: The using statment is nifty, especially since I include a file that defines and includes a lot of junk I don't want to do every single file (assert, vector, etc). However, I dont include that in the header files. There's no way to do a using decleartion globally?